# Difference between Print and Display

Tags: scheme

[PLT Scheme](http://plt-scheme.org/)'s [documentation](http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/103p1/html/mzscheme/node124.htm) says:

> The rationale for providing *print*
>   is that **display** and **write** both
>   have relatively standard output
>   conventions, and this standardization
>   restricts the ways that an environment
>   can change the behavior of these
>   procedures. No output conventions
>   should be assumed for print, so that
>   environments are free to modify the
>   actual output generated by print in
>   any way.

Could somebody please explain what that means for a noob and how is *print* and *display* different?

Comment: It should be noted that it's not a question related to PLT Scheme, but a generic terminology question: is there a conceptual difference between "display" and "write"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that programs can expect certain output formats from `write` and `display`.  In PLT, it is possible to change how they behave, but a little involved to do so.  This is intentional, since doing such a change can have dramatic and unexpected result.

OTOH, changing how `print` behaves is deliberately easy -- just see the `current-print` documentation.  The idea is that `print` is used for debugging, for presenting code to you in an interactive REPL -- *not* as a tool that you will rely on for output that needs to be formatted in a specific way.  (BTW, see also the "~v" directive for `format`, `printf`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You are *free* to override **print** function. If you want to override standardized functions, for example the **write**, you must *obey* to the output standard, otherwise code that use it will possibly break.

About **display** and **write**:

*The Scheme Programming Language*, 3rd edition, pg. 178

```
(display obj)
(display obj output-port)
returns unspecified
```

> **display** is similar to **write**
>   but prints strings and characters
>   found within *obj* directly. Strings
>   are printed without quotation marks or
>   slashes, and characters are printed
>   without #\ notation. For example,
>   both **(display "(a b c)")** and
>   **(display '("a b" c))** would print **(a b c)**. Because of this, **display** should not be used to print objects
>   that are indended to be read with
>   **read**. **display** is useful primarily for printing messages, with
>   *obj* most often being a string.

Comment: In *most* modern Scheme implementations, PLT included, you *cannot* just "override" a function that you didn't define.  IOW, you can write your own definition of `write` or `display`, but it will not affect any code except for your own code.  This is an important principle, otherwise DrScheme (for example) would break left and right.
(That chaos is roughly how Emacs is made...)

Comment: Eli, I agree. And by saying `override` I also mean `re-define`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to replace print you might try out SRFI-28 instead:

http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-28/srfi-28.html

Answer (score -1):

In Python, the print() function is primarily used for debugging and displaying simple text output in the console. It can be used to display the value of a variable, print a message to the user, or log information about the program's execution. The output of print() is often unformatted and lacks visual appeal.

On the other hand, the display() function is typically used in data analysis and visualization to display data in a more organized and aesthetically pleasing format. It is often used in Jupyter notebooks and other interactive environments to show data frames, plots, charts, and other types of graphical representations. The display() function can also be used to format and stylize the output of a data frame or other data structure.

To summarize, print() is primarily used for debugging and displaying simple text output, while display() is used for displaying data in a more organized and visually appealing format, particularly in data analysis and visualization contexts.

ex:
print(dataframe)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WemNi.png)

display(dataframe)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V92Gu.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).